# Knockout change the click event

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, click

I'm trying to find a way to change the click event on all my elements.  I want to do something like this but I think how KO binds the click event its actually attached to the element and so changing the function has no effect.

```
viewModel.clickEvent = function(item){
   logic
}

viewModel.clickEvent = newFunction;

<div data-bind="click: clickeEvent">MyButton</div>
```

I think that I need to use delegates but having a hard time figuring out how to do this.  Could anyone post a basic example of how to do this with knockout?

Comment: Your example -except for some syntax problems- works as expected. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/jMGwj/). What are you trying to achieve? Can you please edit your question and be more specific, make a *working* example that demonstrates your problem more clearly?

Comment: Sorry ya the end goal  was to have the ability to expose the KO click event so that I could alter the logic at run time.  My first attempt was just trying to just set the viewmodel function but this didn't work.  The solution I selected was the path I finally went.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood right. You could create a fake event handler that you can modify without modifying the actual event handler which is binded to the view.

```
var viewModel = {
    clickEvent : function(item){
        if(this.changableClickEvent)
            this.changableClickEvent(item);
    },
    changableClickEvent : null
}

viewModel.changableClickEvent = function(){
    // logic
    alert('logic');
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jMGwj/1/)**

Comment: cool thanks ya I ended up doing something like this but I felt like it was a hack and kept reading about delegates and stuff like that.  This seems much simpler!